# How can I restrict public access modifier in referenced library?

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, restrict

I have two different libraries which refereed the base library called base.dll. One library using for web platforms another one using for windows platform (WPF). I have to restrict restrict one public property in WPF platform but I want to access it in web platform. How can achieve this? I am trying condition compilation but I don’t know how to do exactly. Please help me

For Ex:-
Base library:

```
public Class CommonClass{
    public string CssClass
               {
            get;
            set;
                }
}
```

Referenced Library 1 (Web) – Referenced the base library, need to access CssClass in this library

Referenced Library 2: (WPF) - Referenced the base library, need to restrict CssClass in this library

Answer (score 1):

This actually sounds like a design flaw. You create a library and define which properties should be accessible by users of that library. Normally you don't hide specific properties from specific clients.

However, I think you can achieve what you want by making the property `internal` and use the [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) in your `base.dll`:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("webplatformassembly")]

public Class CommonClass{
    internal string CssClass
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

This way no client can see that property, except those mentioned in a `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute.

See also: [Friend Assemblies (C# and Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk(v=vs.110).aspx)