# How to restrict the usage of property in another project

Tags: c#, .net, properties

We have used one project as dll(common.dll) in both windows application and web application. We have defined one property(webProp) in common.dll. The webProp should visible only in web application only. That property should not visible in windows application.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should extract common interface and extend the interface for web application. Doing so you can hide implementation in common.dll (applications should use interfaces only)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I restrict public access modifier in referenced library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44302553/how-can-i-restrict-public-access-modifier-in-referenced-library)

Comment: Although you can use `InternalVisibleToAttribute` to do this, I would recommend not doing that. So what if the property is visible is visible to the other project, will this cause harm? If yes, then re-think your design. `Internal` stuff even if visible can change and no-one should depend on them. You should try and depend only on public interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can make properties internal, and you would have to rely in [InternalVisibleToAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) to enable property to be visible in webproject and due to usage of internal attribute, its wouldn't be visible in window project.